# AMQP fully-connected broker federation without looping messages

Tags: amqp, publish-subscribe, messagebroker

I'm in the process to plan for a messaging framework and I thought of using an AMQP product (RabbitMQ, OpenMQ, Apache Qpid... etc.) but while searching I found it hard to decide.
the conditions of the network are as follows:

1. Topology: Fully-connected (or completely-connected)
2. Number of Servers: 4
3. Type of messaging: Topic Messaging - publish/subscribe

While reading about the AMQP products it was not so clear how they deal with infinite looping messages in a federation.

- Qpid: clearly states that an ad-hoc connection will cause the problem.
- RabbitMQ: wasn't so clear how to use federation.
- openAMQ: I feel that would solve my issue but still not sure and here comes my
  question!

openAMQ states a fully connected topology example here (as shown in the last figure in the link):
http://www.openamq.org/tutorial:broker-federation

in another document of openAMQ the following statement appears:

http://www.openamq.org/doc:user-3-advanced#toc61

"Federated publish-subscribe creates extra hops when the publisher and subscriber are both on a child server. In this case, messages are sent first to the parent, root server and from there back out to all child servers that need them. This is how we avoid delivering the same message more than once. However it creates extra latency. We would normally put important publishers on the root parent server."

**the first example causes message duplication but the second document talks about this as a limitation in a tree topology(as I did understand)!**

**now.. does openAMQ support a fully-connected network without causing looping messages or not? not could you recommend me a product that doesn't?**

Comment: OpenAQM isn't actively developed any more: http://lists.openamq.org/pipermail/openamq-dev/2010-March/001598.html

Comment: Something very similar to what you want will be in the next RabbitMQ release (which should be out in the next couple of weeks).  Post your question on RabbitMQ Discuss (https://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss) if you want some feedback from the developers.

Answer (score 0):

Qpid will allow duplicate message delivery with certain federation topologies.   It will not go into an infinite loop.  You can mitigate this, but once and only once delivery is on the roadmap.